# Replace Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate fake on nginx-ingress-controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, certificate, kubernetes-ingress, cert-manager

We are running an application on k8s cluster on GKE.

We are using an `nginx-ingress-controller` as external load-balancer Service which is reachable on, let's say, https://12.345.67.98 . We are facing an issue that when we directly access the load-balancer on mentioned URL, we get a certificate warning because a self-signed "Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate" is used.

We only have Ingress objects that are mapping our domains (e.g. app.our-company.com) to Kubernetes services. The nginx load-balancer is a Kubernetes Service with load-balancer type. For SSL/TLS for our domains `cert-manager` is used. There is no issue when accessing these domains, only when we directly access the load-balancer on the IP-Address.

Is there a way to somehow replace the certificate on the load-balancer, so it's not using the default fake certificate anymore?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a secret with your CA signed certificate and the private key. These will have to be base64 encoded in the secret. You will then use this secret in the "tls" section of the ingress manifest.

Ensure that the certificate chain (cert -> intermediate CA -> root CA) is established in the certificate above.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-test
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - foo.bar.com
      # This assumes tls-secret exists and the SSL
      # certificate contains a CN for foo.bar.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: foo.bar.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            # This assumes http-svc exists and routes to healthy endpoints
            serviceName: http-svc
            servicePort: 80
```

[References](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/tls-termination/)

Comment: Let's say someone has done all this, created a secret and referenced it in ingress yml, but Kubernetes still serves that default fake certificate. Where could the issue possibly lie? Could the problem be in ingress controller?

Comment: @lovrodoe were you able to pass this problem, can you share. I am also in same situation.

Comment: @Sanjeev Yes, I solved it. I set `use-http2: "true"` on ingress controller's ConfigMap, under data. And then for each Ingress I've got tls set like in Rakesh Gupta's example. I also had to remove `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect :   "false"` which I had before.

Comment: @lovrodoe Thankyou, unfortunately it is not working. Any other suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can override default SSL certificate during Ingress Controller helm installation.
Ref: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml

```
  ## Additional command line arguments to pass to nginx-ingress-controller
  ## E.g. to specify the default SSL certificate you can use
  ## extraArgs:
  ##   default-ssl-certificate: "<namespace>/<secret_name>"
  extraArgs: {}
```